# Enqueue Javascript Correctly for 3.5

Tags: php, functions, wp-admin, options, jquery-ui

I am trying to create tabs for admin settings page in wp, but I think I'm doing it wrong. The example below shows how I did it but I don't know how to change this to use it correctly with no conflict ie. $.

```
function my_plugin_load_js() {
wp_deregister_script('jquery');
wp_register_script('jquery', 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js');
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

wp_deregister_script('jquery-ui-core');
wp_register_script('jquery-ui-core', 'http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js');
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-core');
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_plugin_load_js' );

function mypluginjs() {
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function() {
   jQuery( "#tabs" ).tabs();
});
</script>';
}
add_action( 'admin_print_scripts', 'mypluginjs' );
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Never de-register core-bundled scripts in the WP-Admin. You shouldn't do it on the *front end*, either, unless you *really, really* know what you're doing. But **especially** in the WP-Admin, just use the core-bundled scripts.

Also, when you use core-bundled jQuery UI, WordPress already knows that jQuery is a dependency.

Just change the first callback to this:

```
function my_plugin_load_js() {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-core');
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_plugin_load_js' );
```

Note: you should be using a *plugin-specific* hook here, to enqueue only on your own Plugin's admin page, rather than enqueueing in the entire WP-Admin.

Also, for jQuery UI **Tabs**, you'll need to enqueue the **`jquery-ui-tabs`** script. Core registers it with all its needed deps, so you can just enqueue it directly:

```
function my_plugin_load_js() {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-tabs');
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_plugin_load_js' );
```

For the second, just properly wrap the script [in no-conflict wrappers](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_wrappers):

```
function mypluginjs() {
    ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   jQuery( "#tabs" ).tabs();
});
</script>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'admin_print_scripts', 'mypluginjs' );
```

Comment: +1, with the caveat that if developer wants to use a CDN-hosted jQuery / jQuery-UI, there's a plugin that will do that safely (i.e. using the same versions as those bundled with WordPress): [Use Google Libraries](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/use-google-libraries/)

Comment: I disagree. Core scripts should **never** be overridden in the WP-Admin (except for *extremely rare* edge cases). [Reference this Trac ticket, as well](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/22896).

Comment: Sure, never except... per Ipstenu in that thread. Sounds good, "except". But I'm not fighting to stop the intent of that Trac, merely pointing out that if developer wants to use a CDN then there is a safe option. Let's see how that Trac discussion plays out.

Comment: Do I need to register the scripts (register_settings)?

Comment: Also for the second one shouldn't I echo out the javascript instead of using php tags inside if the function?

Comment: `register_setting()` has nothing to do with registering *scripts*. You only need to register a script, via `wp_register_script()`, if you intend to *enqueue* it. To do so, you would need to put the script in a `file`, and then register/enqueue that script file.

Comment: *"shouldn't I echo out the javascript instead of using php tags inside if the function?"* - Closing the PHP tags has the same effect as *echoing* the content, and allows you to write the script without nested quote marks.

Comment: I view the source of the settings page and the javascript is loading now. I followed [link](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#default) now could there be possibly anything wrong with the html or done differently to fit wp?

Comment: It's just not working for some reason.

Comment: ok I think I found the problem the html for the tabs is inside a php function, can that cause the tabs not to work? I will check the your answer if you can let me know.

Comment: For the third snippet, shouldn't it be `$( "#tabs" ).tabs();` instead of `jQuery( "#tabs" ).tabs();` since you wrapped it?